# Mobile internet not working via zap proxy

Tags: proxy, kali-linux, owasp, zap

I have to test the native android application on device, so

1. I Installed the zap certificated on my device and set the proxy in my device to my system ip where zap is installed and port to 8085.
2. In zap i have just set the local proxy as 0.0.0.0:8085.

After using a Phone with lolippop os I am able to capture the request for all applicaations, but in response for few applications I am getting error as

```
ZAP Error [java.net.ConnectException]: Connection refused: connect

Stack Trace:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This error is generated only for certain apps (example Instagram,banking).

`

Comment: I realize this is a Jeopardy style flagging but you just don't know the word for what you're looking for. You can't access these sites/apps because they use SSL pinning. What is SSL pinning, see flag.

Comment: I am now able to capture request in ZAP after using phone with Lolipop os.
But Still I am not able to receive the resopnse